# Vscode organizeImports vs eslint import/order how to handle dash or slash

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, eslint, rx-angular

I have the following lines :

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs-zone-less';
import { map, throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

`eslint(import/order)`  is not happy because : `rxjs/operators import should occur before import of rxjs-zone-less`

while VSCode's `source.organizeImports` formats as the former.

Any idea how to fix this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to [this bug](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2685) in the 2.27 of `eslint-plugin-import`.

Reverting back to 2.26 fixes my problem atm.

Comment: I'm on `"eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0"` and I'm getting the same ` bar import should occur before import of foo`  import/order error

Comment: My issue could be due to a different sorting order rule, but still the same idea that the `organizeImports` and `eslint` aren't talking the same talk!